# using vbscript to log into web page

Tags: vbscript

This code gets me to the page and fills in the userid and password fields but after it does the submit I get a response from the application that the userid and password are not valid. If I don't execute the submit command but let the program stop at the page then manually click the login button then I successfully login. It appears eventhough the userid and paasword are being filled in correctly on the form, they are not getting passed through to the next page properly.

Any thoughts? I'm a VBsript newbie.

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://cpprod.stjohns.edu/cp/home/displaylogin"
Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
IE.Document.getElementByID("user").value = "testacct"
WScript.Echo IE.Document.getElementByID("user").value
IE.Document.getElementByID("pass").value = "testpw"
WScript.Echo IE.Document.getElementByID("pass").value
IE.Document.getElementByID("cplogin").submit
```

Comment: I am assuming you are aware that the credentials you have their are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Give the below a try and let me know your results...

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.navigate WebPath

Do
    WScript.Sleep 250
Loop While oIE.ReadyState < 4 And oIE.Busy

oIE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = sUser
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = sPass
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("login").Click
```